# How to create a class literal of a known type: Class<List<String>>

Tags: java, generics, jls

Take the following:

```
public Class<List<String>> getObjectType() {
    // what can I return here?
}
```

What class literal expression can I return from this method which will satisfy the generics and compile? `List.class` won't compile, and neither will `List.<String>class`.

If you're wondering "why", I'm writing an implementation of Spring's `FactoryBean<List<String>>`, which requires me to implement `Class<List<String>> getObjectType()`. However, this is *not* a Spring question.

**edit:** My plaintive cries have been heard by the powers that be at SpringSource, and so Spring 3.0.1 will have the return type of `getObjectType()` changed to `Class<?>`, which neatly avoids the problem.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can always cast to what you need, like

```
return (Class<List<String>>) new ArrayList<String>().getClass();
```

or

```
return (Class<List<String>>) Collections.<String>emptyList().getClass();
```

But I assume that's not what you are after. Well, it works, with a warning, but it isn't exactly "beautiful".

I just found [this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ310):

> ###### Why is there no class literal for wildcard parameterized types?
>
> Because a wildcard parameterized type has no exact runtime type representation.

So casting might be the only way to go.

Comment: Your first example did not work for me (SE 1.6), only the second example did.
Instantiating the ArrayList to a variable and returning myVar.getClass() works though.

found   : java.lang.Class<capture#972 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList>

required: java.lang.Class<java.util.List<com.foo.Bar>>

Answer (score 17):

You should never use the construct `Class<List<String>>`.  It is nonsensical, and should produce a warning in Java (but doesn't).  Class instances always represent raw types, so you can have `Class<List>`; that's it.  If you want something to represent a reified generic type like `List<String>`, you need a "super type token" like Guice uses:

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html

Comment: I agree that it's not a good idea, but Java permits it, and if you're trying to implement an interface, you may have no choice in the matter, so we still need a way of doing it (semi-)elegantly.

Answer (score 14):

You can implement that method like this:

```
public Class<List<String>> getObjectType() {
    return (Class<List<String>>) ((Class)List.class);
}
```

Comment: I like this way because you don't need create a new instances.

Comment: The outer cast is unnecessary. You can write it like this instead: `return (Class)List.class;`, which I find easier to read.

Answer (score 9):

The existence of a `Class<List<String>>` is inherently dangerous.  here's why:

```
// This statement generates a warning - for a reason...
Class<List<String>> unsafeListClass = (Class<List<String>>) (Class<?>) List.class;

List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Ok
integerList.add(42); // Ok

System.out.println(unsafeListClass.isInstance(integerList)); // Prints "true".
List<String> stringList =
   unsafeListClass.cast(integerList); // Succeeds, with no warning!
stringList.add("Hello, World!"); // Also succeeds with no warning

for (int x: integerList) {
    // Compiles without warning, but throws ClassCastException at runtime
    System.out.println(100-x);
}
```

Comment: That is a strange example. Since generics are not reified in runtime runtime casting bypasses the generic type system in many cases. Generics are mostly a compile time construct that allows you to further constrain a type from a class type. It would be useful if you could keep the generic signature because, as long as you don't cast, would make a lot of code more readable AND typesafe.

Answer (score 7):

Found [this link](http://issues.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5982) on springframework.org which gives some insight.

E.g.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
return (Class<List<String>>)myList.getClass();
```

Comment: @Bozho: the springframework link has a different method signature `java.lang.Class<? extends T> getObjectType()`. I've updated my answer to reflect the signature of the OP's question.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"issues.springframework.org | DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"*.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this discussion on the SUN forums:

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5253007

And the referenced blog post that describes a work around by using "super type tokens":

http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Comment: First link in answer is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, since any class literal will be compiled to `Class.forName(...)` and since this happens at runtime there is no generic information left.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Type type = TestMain.class.getMethod("dummy").getGenericReturnType();
        System.out.println("type = " + type);
    }

    public List<Integer> dummy() {return null;}
}
```

This prints:

```
type = java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is problematic:

```
> public Class<List<String>> getModelType() {
>   return (Class<List<String>>) new ArrayList<String>().getClass();
> }
```

e.g. if you want to test whether an object say of type

```
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.BasicEList<String>
```

is of type

```
List<String>
```

based on the result of the aforementioned getModelType() approach, for example:

```
BasicEList<String> fromObject = ...;
if (getModelType().isAssignableFrom(fromObject.getClass())) {
    transferFromModelToUi(getModelType().cast(fromObject));
}
```

it will result in false whereas it should be true because both objects implement the interface List (since getModelType() returns a Class object of type List and not ArrayList).

Here is an approach that worked for me (a bit cumbersome but leads to correct results in the example above, could be moved to a static initializer):

```
public Class<List<String>> getModelType() {
    Class<?> arrayListClass = new ArrayList<String>().getClass();
    Class<?>[] interfaces = arrayListClass.getInterfaces();
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
        if (interfaces[i].equals(List.class)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (Class<List<String>>) interfaces[index];
}
```