# How to instantiate generic variable like Class<Foo<T>>?

Tags: java, generics

I need to instantiate generic variable like Class>.
For example,

```
Class<? extends List<String>> = ...
```

Variant 1:

```
Class<? extends List<String>> clazz = LinkedList.class;
```

don't work - "Incompatible types".

Variant 2:

```
Class<? extends List> clazz = LinkedList.class;
```

work, but in this case List is a raw type - not good.

How to instantiate such variables?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
Class<? extends List<String>> var = (Class<? extends List<String>>)myList.getClass();
```

Comment: Only by means of creation unnecessary object and using getClass() method?

Comment: The object really is unnecessary, the cast alone will do.

Comment: Hmm... unnecessary object is needed:
Class<? extends List<String>> listClass = (Class<? extends List<T>>) ArrayList.class;
compile error - inconvertible types.

Answer (score 7):

There is not really a point in having `Class<List<String>>`, since it would be equivalent to `Class<List<Integer>>` (both being a reference to the raw List due to erasure).

Having said that, if your intention is to represent the `List<String>` type, this is possible, see [TypeLiteral](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) of [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

```
TypeLiteral<List<String>> type = new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {};
System.out.println(type.getType()); //should print List<String>
```

The mechanism that makes it possible is reflection on static type declarations, in either class definition (`class X extends Foo<Y>`, Y is available through reflection, it is preserved in the bytecode), method definitions, etc. TypeLiteral uses the former, you may notice that it creates a brand new class, so the net effect is that your type parameter gets preserved. It's a nice workaround when you are really fighting against erasure.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it *properly*. Either use the raw type or use an unsafe cast.

Comment: @downvoter - perhaps you didn't grasp that "or use an unsafe cast" is practically what the accepted answer means?

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
    class ListString extends java.util.LinkedList<String> { }
    Class<? extends java.util.List<String>> clazz = ListString.class;
```

However, given what `Class` represents, there isn't that much point. You are better off avoiding reflection wherever possible.