# java equivalent for scala classOf[]

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Can any one help me with the Java equivalent of this?

```
wordCountRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputFile,classOf[Text],classOf[IntWritable],classOf[TextOutputFormat[Text,IntWritable]])
```

I tried below : but it give me error at                         TextOutputFormat<>(Text,IntWritable) ..

```
wordCountRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
                        output,
                        Text.class,
                        IntWritable.class,
                        TextOutputFormat<>(Text,IntWritable)
                        context.hadoopConfiguration());
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does? I know Java but I don't know Scala.

Comment: What is `TextOutputFormat<>(Text,IntWritable)` supposed to do?

Comment: sure, TextOutputFormat is to write the output to key and value pairs, where key is Text and value is IntWritable

Comment: i am not sure about the syntax, where should i add the new?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
TextOutputFormat<>(Text,IntWritable)
```

You have to pass the **class** instead:

```
TextOutputFormat.class
```

But note: the java type system doesn't allow you to express something like. `TextOutputFormat<Text,IntWritable>.class`! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745193/why-is-using-collectionstring-class-illegal) for why that is.

From that point of view, TextOutputFormat.class seems to be your only option.

Comment: The precise term for this behavior of generics is [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339708/5699679)