# Java casting ".class"-operator used on a generic type, e.g. List, to "Class<List<?>>" and to "Class<List<Integer>>"

Tags: java, generics, reflection, casting

I use the `.class`-operator to supply information about the contained type to a generic class.  For non-generic contained types, e.g. `Integer.class`, this works without any problems.  But with the contained type being a generic, e.g. `List<Integer>.class` or `List.class` it results in compile time errors about class casting.

There is a way to circumvent the errors, but I'm curious about what is happening here.  Can someone explain what is happening?, why things are as they are?, and what the best way to circumvent the problem is?

The following lines demonstrate the problem:
Note the outer generic type expects `Class<T>` as parameter, so in this case `Class<List<Integer>>`.

```
Class<Integer> tInt = Integer.class;                     // Works as expected.
Class<List> tList = List.class;              // Works with warning, but is not
                                             // what i'm looking for.
Class<List<Integer>> tListInt1 = List.class;                          // Error
Class<List<Integer>> tListInt2 = (Class<List<Integer>>) List.class;   // Error
Class<List<?>> tListGeneric = (Class<List<Integer>>) List.class;      // Error
```

The next line works:

```
Class<List<Integer>> tListInt3 = 
                (Class<List<Integer>>) ((Class<Integer>)List.class);
```

Why do the declarations of `tListInt2` and `tListGeneric` give and error?
Why does upcast and then downcast with `tListInt3` not produce an error?
Is there a better way to declare `tListInt3`?

With kind regards,
Kasper van den Berg

ps. Let me know if you like to see code the outer generic container that needs this type information; i'll post it if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create expressions of type Class<List<?>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Class<List<Integer>> tListInt3 = 
            (Class<List<Integer>>) ((Class<Integer>)List.class);
```

that doesn't work. you probably meant

```
Class<List<Integer>> tListInt3 = 
            (Class<List<Integer>>) ((Class)List.class);
```

we can always cast from one type to another by up-cast then down-cast

```
    Integer x = (Integer)(Object)"string";
```

The type of `List.class` is `Class<List>`; it is not a subtype/supertype of `Class<List<Whatever>>` therefore direct cast between the two types is illegal.

It can be argued that `Class<List<Integer>>` doesn't exist - there is only a class for `List`; there is no such class for `List<Integer>` (which really is just `List` at runtime)

However, this is a flaw of Java type system; in practice we do need things like `Class<List<Integer>>`. Our solution - casting and pretending `Class<List<Int>>` exits - is likewise flawed - but it's not our fault.