# Implement interface with method returning class of type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a 3rd party interface `Converter<PRESENTATION, MODEL>` which contains a method

```
Class<MODEL> getModelType();
```

I need to have an implementation that extends `Converter<String, Id<SOMETYPE>>` so to satisfy the compiler, I need to implement the following method:

```
@Override
public Class<Id<SOMETYPE>> getModelType() {
    return Id<SOMETYPE>.class;  // does not compile
}
```

Is this a corner case where I need to revert to using raw types and implement `Converter<String, Id>` instead (using the raw type `Id`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to type erasure, a `Id<SOMETYPE>.class` is the same as a `Id.class`, except that you can't return the former or the latter (compile error). So you need to trick the compiler, for example:

```
@Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<List<String>> getModelType() {
    return (Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this problem as well. This is the question that helped me:

[Java casting ".class"-operator used on a generic type, e.g. List, to "Class<List<?>>" and to "Class<List<Integer>>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502243/java-casting-class-operator-used-on-a-generic-type-e-g-list-to-classlist)

The solution in your case is this:

```
public interface Converter<PRESENTATION, MODEL>  {
    Class<MODEL> getModelType();
}

interface Id<E>  {
}

class MyConverter<E> implements Converter<String, Id<E>>  {
    @Override
    public Class<Id<E>> getModelType() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  //We know this is okay
        Class<Id<E>> cls = (Class<Id<E>>)(Class)Id.class;
         return  cls;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning a similar question, I didn't find any.