# migrating java classes to use generics

Tags: java, generics

I have problem to use generics in one of my class. These are my classes:

```
public interface InterE<PK> {}

public interface Inter2<O extends ClassO, P extends ClassP> {}

public class ClassU<O extends ClassO, P extends ClassP> implements InterE<Long> {}

public class ClassP {}

public class ClassO {}

public class Class1<PK, T extends InterE<PK>> {
    public Class1 (Class<T> clazz) {}
}

public class Class2<O extends ClassO, P extends ClassP> extends Class1<Long, ClassU<O, P>> implements Inter2<O, P> {
    public Class2 () {
        //old constructor
        //super(ClassU.class);
        //new - here is problem
        super(ClassU<O, P>.class);
    }
}
```

If ClassU does not use generics, then old constructor in Class2 works fine, but I need to use generics in ClassU, so I have problem to call super constructor in Class2.

Comment: What exactly happens when you just use the constructor in the "old" way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: @serg.nechaev not quite, he's not looking for `O.class` or `P.class`.

Comment: old way has compilation error - The constructor Class1<Long,ClassU<O,P>>(Class<ClassU>) is undefined

Comment: [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2390662/3004881) explains why you're having a problem, but I'm not seeing any good solutions there...

Comment: There is probably no safe way around it, but you can use an unsafe double cast: `super((Class<ClassU<O, P>>)(Class)ClassU.class)`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502243/java-casting-class-operator-used-on-a-generic-type-e-g-list-to-classlist

Comment: @dhke No I can't. there is "Cannot cast from Class to ClassU<O,P>" error

Comment: Using `(Class<?>)` instead of `(Class)` for the first cast worked for me.

Comment: @podmak: Can you try again with the corrected version? There was an error in my initial version. The correction gives an unchecked cast warning, but compiles and runs just fine with Java 8.

Comment: it looks like super((Class) ClassU.class); is without compilation error too. I ran some tests. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

**Short story:** change `Class1` constructor parameter type - from `Class<T>` to `Class<?>`.

Why?

`Class1` only needs `T` to extend `InterE`. `Class2` declares `ClassU` to be this `T` argument. Since `ClassU` implements `InterE`, everything is OK for `Class1`.

Do you really need this `<T>` information in `Class1` constructor? I think no:
1) `T` is already present in class declaration: `Class1<PK, T extends InterE<PK>>`, you can use it inside the class to generify code and make it compile-time safe:

```
 public class Class1<PK, T extends InterE<PK>> {
     Map<PK, T> map = new HashMap<>(); // can still use T, compile-time safe
 }
```

2) What can `Class<T>` do, that `Class<?>` can not do? - it can create `newInstance()` safe and do some more stuff, but you most likely won't use this possibility. Use still can operate with `T`, for example call `T instance = (T) class.newInstance();`, so you will not have any insuperable limitations.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In Class1 is nothing special. It is used mostly for checking to avoid bad input to constructor and exception during runtime

Comment: @podmak if the answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted, so other users could use it. otherwise, write why it doesn't solve the problem or edit the original question.

Comment: You should not use raw types, see [my comment on podmaks answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860063/migrating-java-classes-to-use-generics/30863772#comment49790093_30865422).

Comment: @siegi ok, i changed it

Comment: @AdamSkywalker is absolutely right that T is already available on Class1 to add type-safety and Class2 extends Class1, so requiring it to be passed in is redundant

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your example why you need to preserve the parameter; once you understand [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and how generics are a compile-time check, not a runtime check, not all generics will necessarily make sense.

If you do want to preserve and operate upon parametrized types at runtime, [Google's Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library provides [TypeToken](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained), e.g.

```
public class Class1<PK, T extends InterE<PK>> {
    public Class1 (TypeToken<T> token) {}
}

public class Class2<O extends ClassO, P extends ClassP> extends Class1<Long, ClassU<O, P>> implements Inter2<O, P> {
    public Class2 () {
        super(new TypeToken<ClassU<O, P>>() {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dkhe answer was right:
`super((Class<ClassU<O, P>>) (Class) ClassU.class)`

and also worked for me:
`super((Class) ClassU.class)`

Comment: You should not use `Class` without type parameters (called a _raw type_). From the [Java Language Specification, §4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8): _The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types […] is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions […] will disallow the use of raw types._ Better use `Class<?>` as [Damsen shows in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30863772/1347968).

Comment: casting to `Class<?>` results as compilation error - undifined constructor

Comment: All the casting is bending over backwards to make the compiler happy by casting, which isn't type-safe. This defeats the point of trying to use the generics in the first place - to provide type safety at compile time - as the types are erased come runtime.

Comment: @podmak: The first form should work when `(Class)` is replaced with `(Class<?>)`. The second form disables generics completely for this statement as you are using a _raw type_. I guess you got the compilation error when adding the `<?>` to the second form (which is expected not to work)…

Comment: @Danikov: As I already said [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860063/migrating-java-classes-to-use-generics/30865422?noredirect=1#comment49789856_30863772): I agree that casting defeats the purpose of type safety _in most cases_. But can you show me an example of a problem caused by casting a `Class` instance as in the case above?

Comment: @siegi In this specific case, all the generics are doing is checking that you cast correctly. Casting doesn't check that the cast is possible, hence being an unsafe operation. You could put *anything* to the right of the cast and it will compile, at in same manner, you could cast to anything in the cast. If either of these ever refactored to be incompatible, the issue won't be discovered until runtime because of the lack of safety in the cast operation. This is the opposite of what generics are meant to achieve.

Comment: @Danikov: You cannot know what the OP wants to use the `Class` object for or why he designed the generic types of the classes and interfaces the way he did, at least I do not. Each cast is unsafe by definition. If it would be safe, the compiler would not require the cast in the first place. Nevertheless, if you take the definition of the classes, interfaces and constructors as fixed, you have no option but to cast. So it's the only valid answer to the OPs question. Of course the use of `TypeToken` as you demonstrate in your answer is better, but it requires altering the constructors signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
super((Class<ClassU<O, P>>)(Class<?>)ClassU.class);
```

Reference: [Class object of generic class (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java)

Comment: Wanton casting isn't type-safe, which defeats the point of having the generics in the first place.

Comment: @Danikov: I agree that this type of casting defeats the purpose of generics _in most cases_ but `Class` is a special case as you cannot get a `Class` object with a specific generic type.

Comment: @siegi It's very easy to get `Class<String>`. The problem is something like `Class<Map<?,?>>`.

Comment: @Danikov: Yes, sorry, I wasn't clear on that. But the point remains: How are you supposed to get a `Class<Map<?,?>>` or a `Class<ClassU<O,P>>` without casting?

Comment: @siegi You can't, but more importantly, it doesn't make sense to. Remember that types are erased at runtime and only checked at compile time, but also that generics are only resolved with instances. When you ask for the Class of an object, that is a static property. The information doesn't exist at that scope. That's why Guava's `TypeToken` works both at compile and runtime, due to the anonymous instantiation.

Comment: @Danikov: I understand that and, as I said, I agree that casting can be problematic. I agree `TypeToken` is a better option than `Class` for generic types. But how could you ever call a method like `void foo(Class<T> clazz, T object)` (that may be defined in a third party library) on an object with `T` bound to `List<String>` without casting? Such a method should probably be redesigned but I would be very surprised if there is no library containing such a method.

Comment: @siegi The answer is that you cannot submit `List<String>`, you can only capture List as a raw type, e.g. `List.class`. new ArrayList<AnyType>().getClass() only returns ArrayList<?>, which makes sense because of erasure; fundamentally type safety has been achieved at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is:

```
public class Class1<PK, T extends InterE<PK>> {
     public Class1 (Class<? extends T> clazz) {}
}


public class Class2<O extends ClassO, P extends ClassP> extends Class1<Long, ClassU<O, P>> implements Inter2<O, P> {
    public Class2 () {
       super((Class<? extends ClassU<O, P>>) ClassU.class);
    }}
```

**EDIT**

Valid for Java 1.6

Comment: This gives me the same error as the OP's code. Doesn't it give you an error, too?

Comment: Sorry, @DanGetz, you are right. Constructor should be:             `super((Class<? extends ClassU<O, P>>) ClassU.class);`

Comment: I'm still getting an error.

Comment: I tests this on java 1.6. Which version of java do you use?

Comment: 1.7, maybe that's the difference.

Comment: No, I'm seeing an error on 1.6 also.

Comment: Works for me on 1.6.

Comment: Seems to work in Eclipse but not with `javac`, independent of the Java version used. May be related to [Eclipse bug 332516](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332516) but I've not taken a deeper look at it…

Comment: @siegi, it doesn't work for me on 1.7, but work on 1.6. I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: @DenysDenysiuk what exact version of 1.6? OpenJDK 1.6 update 35 gives me the same error as with 1.7. Are you sure you're using the exact code posted here?

Comment: `C:\Users\ddenysiuk>java -version`

`java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)`

Yes, I'm sure.