# How to get class variable of List

Tags: java, class

Getting `.class` of a class in Java is like:

```
Model.class
```

However how can I get  `.class` of that:

```
List<Model>
```

to pass it a function like:

```
public List<T> getX(Class<List<T>> clz) {
   ...
}
```

I tried that:

```
(Class<List<Model>>) new ArrayList<Model>().getClass();
```

However it gives me that error:

```
inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Class<capture#181 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList>
required: java.lang.Class<java.util.List<a.b.c.Model>>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create expressions of type Class<List<?>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist)

Comment: isn't `T` something more specific? For ex ample `List<Device>` getX(..)`

Comment: @Bozho I edited my question it was `Model` instead of `Device`

Comment: I meant the `getX(..)` method should not use the T parameter, but the concrete class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to change your method to something like this:

```
public List<T> getX(List<T> list) {
    ... = list.getClass();
    ... = list.getClass ().getGenericSuperclass ();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Model>
```

is not available at runtime.

Java implements generics through type erasure [fancy way of saying they substitute it with object] as opposed to say C# implementation due to backward compatibility reasons.

So one option is:

```
public static <T> void getX(Class<List> clz, T type);
```

and call it like:

```
getX(List.class, vals);
```