# Java: Generic types in a type token

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class which takes a type token, and then generates objects of a type parameterized by that type (OK, it's a bit more complicated than that, but this is a concise example):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Holder<HashSet<Integer>> i = newObjectHolder(HashSet.class);  // this fails
    }

    static class Holder<T> {
        public Holder(T newInstance) {}
    }

    public static <T> Holder<T> newObjectHolder(Class<T> typeToken) throws Exception {
        Constructor<T> ctor = typeToken.getConstructor();
        return new Holder<T>(ctor.newInstance());
    }
}
```

This works fine if passed non-generic types, like:

```
Holder<Integer> i = Test.newObjectHolder(Integer.class);
```

If the passed type token is generic, however, it doesn't work, as in the indicated line above:

```
Holder<HashSet<Integer>> i = Test.newObjectHolder(HashSet.class);  // this fails
```

I get the problem, but is there a solution?  I'm OK to add @SuppressWarnings("unused") in the code for `newObject`, if it doesn't reduce the safety.  Intuitively, it seems that newObject should be able to to make a cast that works, we know that one "new" object of an erased generic type is the same as any other, and we haven't otherwise used `T` in the method.

Comment: That was an error, introduced during my "make concise" phase from the real code.  Let me fix it.

Comment: Fixed.  Note that it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the call to `Foo.newObject` supposed to be to `Foo.newObjectHolder`?

Comment: Yes, my example was inconsistent after earlier edits to fix problems raised by Nishant.  I've updated it now with a http://sscce.org/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, sheepishly, answering my own question...

I can't find any way to do it with `Class<?>`, but this magic technique called *super* type tokens seems to work well.  Here's the updated code:

```
public class Test {

    static class A {}
    static class B extends A {}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Holder<HashSet<Integer>> i = newObjectHolder(new TypeReference<HashSet<Integer>>() {});  // works
        Holder<A> j = newObjectHolder(new TypeReference<A>() {});  // works
        Holder<A> k = newObjectHolder(new TypeReference<B>() {});  // works
        Holder<B> l = newObjectHolder(new TypeReference<A>() {});  // doesn't compile (good)
    }

    static class Holder<T> {
        public Holder(T newInstance) {}
        T get() { return null; }
    }

    public static <T,U extends TypeReference<? extends T>> Holder<T> newObjectHolder(U typeToken) throws Exception {
        T obj = typeToken.newInstance();
        return new Holder<T>(obj);
    }
}
```

The `TypeReference` code is given [here](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html), although I suspect that Guice's [`TypeLiteral`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) would work just as well (but it doesn't have newInstance code, you'd have to implement it).

Comment: Yup, as soon as I saw the question title I immediately thought of the super type tokens technique.

Comment: Answering your own question is great! Don't forget to accept your answer.

Comment: @Taymon - I was happy I was able to answer it, yeah, but I feel guilty because it basically means that maybe I didn't do enough experimentation or digging before turning to SO.

Usually I get my answers from SO not by asking, but by finding an existing question (so often they are at the top of Google results these days), so maybe having this one here will help others!

Comment: You shouldn't feel guilty. Your answer still helps others.

Comment: As a follow up, this technique is used by jackson to pass information about generic types to be [de]serialized, [like this](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.html).

Answer (score 1):

In your, now updated, code, you still can

```
 Holder<HashSet> i = newObjectHolder(HashSet.class);
```

but can't

```
 Holder<HashSet<Integer>> i = newObjectHolder(HashSet.class);
```

---

Old answer:

<strike>I am not sure what problem you're getting. This code works alright.</strike>

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashSet<Integer> i = newObject(HashSet.class);
        i.add(new Integer(42));
        i.add(new Integer(666));
        System.out.println(i.size() +":" + Arrays.toString(i.toArray()));
    }

    public static <T> T newObject(Class<T> typeToken) throws Exception {
        Constructor<T> ctor = typeToken.getConstructor();
        return ctor.newInstance();
    }

}
```

prints

```
2:[666, 42]
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You are right, my simplification was too much (although the code above has an unchecked warning).

Let me fix the question.

Comment: yep, with the little knowledge that I have about generics, I think that's inevitable.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.  The error based on your example (calling newObjectHolder) is now:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test.Holder<HashSet> to Test.Holder<HashSet<Integer>>

Comment: Yes, I still fail at maintaining consistency between my example and real life.  What I want to do is: Holder<HashSet<Integer>> i...

Comment: Eventually I need to call methods on Holder, and these should return `HashSet<Integer>` not just `HashSet`.