# Spring Conversion Service: how to convert String to List<MyType>?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, type-conversion, spring-3

I am using Spring's Conversion Service, and have my own converter registered with it:

```
public class MyTypeConverter implements Converter<String, MyType> {
    @Override
    public Currency convert(String text) {
        MyType object = new MyType();
        // do some more work here...
        return object;
    }
}
```

Now in my application I can do conversion from `String` to `MyType` and it works well:

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService cs;

public void doIt() {
    MyType object = cs.convert("Value1", MyType.class);
}
```

But I also noticed, for example, that I can use the same converter within my MVC Controller, and it does somehow work with lists too:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "...")
@ResponseBody
public final String doIt(@RequestParam("param1") List<MyType> objects) throws Exception {
    // ....
}
```

So if I do submit `param1=value1,value2` in controller I do receive a `List<MyType>` with two elements in it. So spring does split the String by commas and then converts each element separately to `MyType`. Is it possible to do this programmatically as well?

I would need something similar like this:

```
List<MyType> objects = cs.convert("Value1,Value2", List<MyType>.class);
```

Comment: what happens when you call `cs.convert("Value1,Value2", List<MyType>.class);`? Some exception is thrown?

Comment: @jelies:Eclipse says me "List cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-expressions-of-type-classlist) answer, it may help.

Comment: Note that because of Java's generic implementation using type erasure, `List<MyType>.class` is exactly equivalent to `List.class` - the type of element stored in the list is lost at run time.  Therefore Spring *cannot* use it to change its conversion behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found pretty close solution myself:

```
List<MyType> objects = Arrays.asList(cs.convert("Value1,Value2", MyType[].class));
```

Would be nicer if Conversion Service would create list automatically, but it is not a big overhead to use `Arrays.asList()` to do it yourself.

Comment: This is the only solution which seems to be working.