# Spring MVC form value conversion

Tags: java, spring-mvc, converters

I have a form which takes a String. The String is structured to represent a list of dates  (ie [01/01/2000 00:00:00, 01/01/2001 00:00:00] as a String would be 2 separate entries in the list, the dates are not common Java Date objects either, they are a custom type).

When the form is submitted, I am expecting the String to List DateTime converter to be called (Below), which it never is. I have a number of other converters working so the Conversion Service is set up correctly. The only thing I can think of is that the type patterns for converting from and to are not what I am expecting.

Does Spring implicitly convert Lists implicitly? Does the Spring form annotation of form:input or form:textarea make any difference to the input type of conversion?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, List<DateTime>> {

@Override
public List<DateTime> convert(String arg) {//Do Stuff}

}
```

This is the controller method signature for when the conversion should be called

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newRequest(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("newSR") ServiceRequest inSR,
        BindingResult result, Model model)
```

The List DateTime attribute is inside of the object inSR.

Comment: show the controller method signature (the one that you expect to result in a call to the DateTimeConverter).

Comment: @DwB Added the controller method

Comment: Did you register the converter in your webmvc-config.xml?

Comment: @fredjam Yep, it is part of a bean set. The other converters are working but they are patterned against simpler types like string to single custom object.

Comment: If they are coming in comma seperated spring might do it automatically if you just register your converter as string -> date. I haven't tried it, but see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825992/spring-conversion-service-how-to-convert-string-to-listmytype

Comment: @fredjam Just tried changing the converter to String -> DateTime and it still isn't called. It looks like for some reason the pattern is not being matched!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am never really sure of how generic types are processed by converters so I generally avoid letting Spring decide what should be done by using a specific type.

In that use case, you could create a simple class :

```
public class DateList {
    private List<DateTime> list;
    // getter, setter or any other useful method ommitted for brevity
}
```

Then if you use a `DateList` field in your form, and register a `Converter<String, DateList>`, it should work.

Comment: Although this isn't exactly an answer, it is the only way I could get it to call the converter, having an encapsulating object and calling the convert on that. Thanks.