# How can I resolve this situation with Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, reflection

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class MyParentObject {}
public abstract class MyObject<T> extends MyParentObject {}

public abstract class MyParentContainer<T extends MyParentObject> {
    private Class<T> valueType;
    protected MyParentContainer(Class<T> valueType) {
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }
}
public abstract class MyObjectContainer<T extends MyObject<?>> extends MyParentContainer<T> {
    protected MyObjectContainer(Class<T> valueType) {
        super(valueType);
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. There are several subclasses of `MyObject` and several container classes having some of those subclasses as `valueType`, e.g.

```
public class IntObject extends MyObject<Integer> {}
public class IntContainer extends MyObjectContainer<IntObject> {
    public IntContainer() {
        super(IntObject.class);
    }
}
```

Now I need to implement a container though that works with a mixed set of subclasses of `MyObject`.

```
public class AllObjectContainer extends MyObjectContainer<MyObject<?>> {
    public AllObjectContainer() {
        super(MyObject.class); // compile error here
    }
}
```

This does not compile, because "The constructor MyObjectContainer<MyObject>(Class) is undefined". Casting `MyObject.class` to `Class>` is not possible.

To solve this, I could use raw types:

1. Change `public class AllObjectContainer extends MyObjectContainer<MyObject<?>>` to `public class AllObjectContainer extends MyObjectContainer<MyObject>`

This has consequences though because of type erasure, so I do not like this solution.

Alternatively I could enable casting by

1. Change `protected MyObjectContainer(Class<T> valueType) {` to `protected MyObjectContainer(Class<? extends T> valueType) {` (add `? extends`)
2. Change `super(MyObject.class)` to `super((Class<? extends MyObject<?>>) MyObject.class)`

This method works, but the cast is marked as unchecked and changing the `MyMiddleContainer`-Constructor has potential side effects on other classes that extend it.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Why do you need the `Class` object? What are you doing with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012306/how-to-create-a-class-literal-of-a-known-type-classliststring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments about reflection and that this code is not the sign of the best implementation are true and valid and everyone who stumbles upon this answer **should read and consider them**.

Yet, in my case, it was not possible to get rid of the reflection altogether, because the `Class` value was passed on to another class that is not under my control - whether that is good is another question (I guess, the answer is 'no'), but not in the scope of this question.

I solved my problem in the following way:

1. removed the `valueType` parameter from the constructor
2. added `protected abstract Class<T> getValueType();` to `MyParentContainer`

Then I implemented the method in the following ways:

```
public class IntContainer extends MyObjectContainer<IntObject> {
    protected Class<T> getValueType() {
        return IntObject.class;
    }
}

public class AllObjectContainer extends MyObjectContainer<MyObject<?>> {
    protected Class<T> getValueType() {
        return (Class<MyObject<?>>) (Class<?>) MyObject.class;
    }
}
```

The dual cast is not pretty, I am totally aware of that. Yet it is in a confined location, it is obvious that it is possible to cast and it fixes the "cannot cast" error.

Answer (score 1):

So, `MyClass.class` is of type `Class<MyClass>` not `Class<MyClass<?>>`.

This is really a question about reflection.

The usual good solution to the problem of reflection is not to use reflection.

I suggest removing the use of `Class` and replace with an interface of the operations you want. You can then, if you wish, place reflection nastiness within a particular implementation of that interface.